# (For a Novel) Plausible Approach to Decrypt Encrypted Image Files?

Tags: encryption

Cryptographic Mavens,

Would you be so kind as to offer a bit of background for a cryptographically-related scene in a novel?

Assume the good guy has to decrypt a dozen image files...yet does not know either the system used to encrypt the files, or their key(s).

Unlike the TV/Movie hackers who crack such files after ~5 seconds of furious keyboarding...what (in your opinion) would be **plausible** (not necessarily through or completely accurate) approaches to (1) determining how the files were encrypted (*i.e.,* what encryption system was used?), and (2) how to attempt decrypting them for viewing?

Your suggestions...thoughts...ideas--maybe even a reference or two (Amazon?)--will be gratefully appreciated.

Thank you,

*Plane Wryter*

Comment: The only plausible algorithm I can suggest is the [Rubber Hose algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber-hose_cryptanalysis).

Comment: Actually, let me revise that. There is no plausible way to breaking a good modern encryption algo. However, many implementations have subtle  bugs in that leave them wide open to cracking. Even so, its pretty hard to do so. Additionally, in most consumer grade encryption, the file format and headers will tell you which algorithm was used. But for mil spec protocols, no chance. Then at the highest end of the scale, we have OTP, which was popular with Soviet spies back in the day. The CIA knew that OTP was being used, but mathematically speaking, cracking is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A reasonably good encryption algorithm will yield data that is statistically almost pure normally-distributed "random" data. (i.e. undecipherable, unrecognizable, high entropy)

The only way you could do this was to brute-force passwords through a brute-force list of password-derivation functions, into a brute-force list of crypto algorithms (i.e. *really freaking hard*).